# How to get the primary email from the member of organization repo using python requests? I am getting none

Tags: python, github, python-requests, github-api

Code:

```py
import requests

def get_organization_members(org_name, access_token):
    url = f'https://api.github.com/orgs/{org_name}/members'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}'}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        members = response.json()
        return members
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        return None

def get_user_info(username, access_token):
    url = f'https://api.github.com/users/{username}'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'token {access_token}'}
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        user_info = response.json()
        return user_info
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        return None


org_name="ss"
access_token="lmsa"

members = get_organization_members(org_name, access_token)

if members:
    print("Members:")
    for member in members:
        username = member['login']
        user_info = get_user_info(username, access_token)
        
        if user_info:
            print(f"Username: {username}")
            print(f"Last Login: {user_info.get('updated_at', 'Not available')}")
            print(f"Email: {user_info.get('email', 'Not available')}")
```

Output:

```
Username: Username1
Last Login: 2023-12-06T02:28:12Z
Email: None
---
Username: Username2
Last Login: 2023-12-18T03:55:34Z
Email: None
---
```

How to get the primary email or users who are member of org?

Comment: The obvious explanation is that those users really did not set an email address in their github profile.  Why were you expecting otherwise?